# Class has unsupported major or minor version numbers

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee

In Eclipse I created an EAR project linked to an ejb and a model. I ran the EAR and I got the following error:

> cannot Deploy earkmz
>
> deploy is failing=Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [earkmz] : UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class it.j2ee.kmZ.business.impl.JPACartService has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.6.0_43. Please see server.log for more details.

I've got only one JRE on my system (1.6.0_43), so it's not possible that I wrongly compiled my classes with another JDK version.

I checked that my settings were right under `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 1.6`.

My project classes are copy-pasted from another project, but I tried to write them from scratch and the result is the same. What am I missing here?

Comment: How do you compile and assemble your project? Do you realize that usually you don't compile with JRE but with JDK? Which dependencies do you use? App server?

Comment: @AndersR.Bystrup I wrote that my settings seem to be right, to exclude the hypothesis that my question could be a duplicate of an older one. I compile my project simply running it on Eclipse. I wrongly wrote "JRE" instead of "JDK", I'll edit my question :) I'm using Glassfish 3.

Comment: Fair one. Are you absolutely sure Glassfish is running on 160_43 and are you absolutely sure that you're not creating a Java7 artifact and are you absolutely sure that you don't have a Java7 dependency in the EAR?

Comment: I think I found the problem. My global Preference settings (the ones from `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 1.6`) did not affect my model project. Editing its dedicated settings revealed that its compiler was set on 1.7 version. I feel quite ashamed for this blunder. Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do check

Project -> Properties -> Java Compiler

and set the compliance level over there as 1.6.

Comment: I think you got it. My global Preference setting (the ones from `Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Compiler compliance level > 1.6`) did not seem to affect my specific model project. Editing its dedicated settings revealed that its compiler was set on 1.7 version. As I said in a previous comment, I feel quite ashamed for this blunder.

Answer (score 0):

It could be because some of the jar[that you might have included in your EAR] is compiled with different version.

Comment: Does `it.j2ee.kmZ.business.impl.JPACartService` class extends a class which is in some jar that you included in your classpath?